# How to use System.Drawing. Common package in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, .net-core, gdi+

I am using System.Drawing.Common (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) package in .NET Core application to create bitmap image using GDI+. When I use the same package in Xamarin application which throws PlatformNotSupported exception.

Is anyone know when Xamarin support will be provided for this package?

Comment: Never. If you need a cross platform drawing API, try SkiaSharp

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will ever be supported. GDI+ is very specific to the Windows platform. If you need any drawing library, you could have a look at SkiaSharp, which is supported by Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace System.Drawing.Common with [Aspose.Drawing](https://products.aspose.com/drawing/net) that has the same API and truly cross-platform. (I'm one of the developers.)